# How can I easily see which COM port is used by Arduino?

Tags: windows

I'm rather disappointed because I just bought arduino and I am unable to upload any projects. The error I get is:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM3": Časový limit semaforu vypršel.
```

Can be translated as:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM3": Semaphore time out
```

Am I expected to brute-force all available ports to see which one is reserved for arduino? How can I, on Windows 7, quickly determine which port to use given that the IDE for some reason can't do that for me.

Comment: I'd look into the Device Manager.

Comment: This has nothing to do with electronics design. You are best off searching on something like SuperUser or Arduino.SE to find out how to locate serial ports in windows and the Arduino IDE respectively.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I didn't know Arduino.SE has been resurrected *again* (how many times was it already...?). And many of those who said Arduino.SE should not be created argumented that **all** Arduino quesrions can be answered on Electronics.SE.

Comment: Looks like EE.SE doesn't agree with you. :) The IDE should detect which port the Arduino is on. I never have to brute-force search for mine. `I just bought arduino` - which Arduino? You may have to install a device driver. There is a "drivers" directory with some in it.

Comment: @NickGammon Do not misunderstand. I am supporting Arduino.SE! I just didn't know it's resurrected - I had all my questions from previous betas migrated. Although I see that I already have some question here. Maybe I forgot. And after installing drivers, the arduino now appears next to the correct port, though I still have to manually select it.

Comment: Glad that helped. I turned my comment into an answer to make it more permanent. I have found on Windows / Ubuntu and Mac that if you unplug and replug the Arduino, it often gets assigned a different (COM) port and you may need to select it from the `Tools -> Port` menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start | Control Panel | System | Device Manager | Ports (COM & LTP).

Watch the list change as you plug / unplug the Arduino. The new port is the Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to install a device driver. There is a "drivers" directory in the IDE download with some in it.

Example:

[image: Windows drivers]

According to the readme.txt file:

> With this version of Arduino a new all-in-one driver (with
>   security signature for Windows 8) is supplied.
>
> The old (deprecated) drivers are still available in the
>   Old_Arduino_Drivers.zip